# How to change the size of sprite nodes to fit different screens in sprite kit (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a game and I'm almost finished, however the one annoying problem that I am having is that my game will not fit the IPhone 5 screen. I have used size classes, set the scale to aspect fill, even tried resize fill, but it won't fit on the iPhone 5.  It fits on all other screen sizes ( except iPhone 4s because I'm not supporting it) including the iPad.  Are there any other options other than size classes? Do I have to programmatically change the images? If so, how would I do that in sprite kit?

Comment: This makes no sense, you have 3 cases 4:3(iPad), 16:9(>=iPhone 5), and 3:2(iphone 4s)  If it doesnt fit in any of these 3, then it wont fit on anything at all.  The only way it will not fit, is if you use resize fill, and develop your coordinates around a larger screen size,  but if this is the case,  then all your devices will be laid out differently

Comment: You should not be dealing with size classes,  that is reserved for UIViews,  so unless your sprite scene is a tiny window,  leave it to the default

Comment: What are those three cases that you used ?

Comment: those are the available aspects on ios devices

Comment: I'm confused, so i should use the universal ? I developed the images to fit the iPhone 6 initially.  So then, if I don't use size classes, how will I fit my images on the other screen sizes?

Comment: btw, you HAVE to support 4s, won't go on the market without the support for it

Comment: if you develop your scene around iphone 6, then it should scale down to iphone 5 and 5s.  Make sure your scene size is set to iphone 6 size, then it will scale based on that

Comment: Alright, well, if I have developed these images to fit on the iPhone 6/ iPhone then how can i scale it ?

Comment: So will it scale to the iPad as well then ?

Comment: it will scale to all devices,  it is a matter of what type of scaling you want

Comment: Ok, i apologize also, but so basically you want me to have the images on universal that are set for the iPhone 6, and then it will automatically resize? I have tried that and it didn't work. How will I determine these three cases and scale everything through that

Comment: the images do not resize, your scene scales, and everything in the scene scales.  Yes, make all images universal in your assets.  make your scene size the size of iphone 6.  pick any scale mode other than .resize, because resize is not what you want, You use resize when you want people with bigger devices to see more of the scene than those with smaller sizes

Comment: Alright I will try and do it.  Do I need to look up the iPhone 6 dimensions and then set the scene width and height to those before the scene is rendered ?

Comment: just set it in the sks file

Comment: if you are doing `let scene = GameScene(size)` then I would recommend stop doing that,  there are terrible tutorials that say to do this without telling you why.  There is a reason sks files exist, and it makes your life 1000 times easier to properly use them

Comment: I will try it. Thanks !

Comment: and yea i did do that

Comment: doing it that way makes the scene ignore the scalemode size,  essentially it becomes a .ResizeFill, which is not what people want,  It is a shame that the tutorials do not explain this.  There is no reason to ever set the scene size to the view size, because that is what .ResizeFill does for you.  The only time you want to use GameScene(size) is if you want your scene to be a specific size, and scaled across devices, without having the sks file.  Again, this is bad, because you should always try to separate design from implementation, so that is why you should be using the sks file

Comment: So all i do in the sks file is input the  iPhone 6 dimensions of 1334 x 750 and then it should scale down to the iPhone 5 / iPhone 4s etc ?

Comment: it will scale up and down,  then for devices like iphone 4s and ipad, they will lose some of the top and bottom  (Providing you use the .AspectFill scale, if you use .AspectFit, they will get black borders, if you use .Fill, they will get squished)

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work for me when i just tried it.  But thanks anyway

Comment: did you make the gamescene actually use the sks file

Comment: let sceneView = view as! SKView
        // sceneView.showsFPS = true
        // sceneView.showsNodeCount = true
        sceneView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        
        let scene = MainMenu()
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        sceneView.presentScene(scene)

Comment: wait how do you do that ?

Comment: no, you need to do MainMenu(fileNamed:"MainMenu")  providing main menu is the name of the sks

Comment: Oh that means i need another Sks file then

Comment: no,  just whatever the sks file name is, shove it in the string part

Comment: i have the sks file for my game scene . So if i want my main menu to scale the same way i would need a new sks file correct ?

Comment: no, you can use the same sks file,  for this purpose

Comment: in the future though,  you could actually create the sks file for your menu, and design the menu visually in the sks builder

Comment: Wow, i will have to do some more research.  Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do it is to detect what device the user is using, then changing a variable to meet that device.

Here is an extension using UIDevice() that you can detect what device the user is on:

```
public extension UIDevice {

var modelName: String {
    var systemInfo = utsname()
    uname(&systemInfo)
    let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
    let identifier = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
        guard let value = element.value as? Int8 where value != 0 else { return identifier }
        return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
    }

    switch identifier {
    case "iPod5,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 5"
    case "iPod7,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 6"
    case "iPhone3,1", "iPhone3,2", "iPhone3,3":     return "iPhone 4"
    case "iPhone4,1":                               return "iPhone 4s"
    case "iPhone5,1", "iPhone5,2":                  return "iPhone 5"
    case "iPhone5,3", "iPhone5,4":                  return "iPhone 5c"
    case "iPhone6,1", "iPhone6,2":                  return "iPhone 5s"
    case "iPhone7,2":                               return "iPhone 6"
    case "iPhone7,1":                               return "iPhone 6 Plus"
    case "iPhone8,1":                               return "iPhone 6s"
    case "iPhone8,2":                               return "iPhone 6s Plus"
    case "iPhone8,4":                               return "iPhone SE"
    case "iPad2,1", "iPad2,2", "iPad2,3", "iPad2,4":return "iPad 2"
    case "iPad3,1", "iPad3,2", "iPad3,3":           return "iPad 3"
    case "iPad3,4", "iPad3,5", "iPad3,6":           return "iPad 4"
    case "iPad4,1", "iPad4,2", "iPad4,3":           return "iPad Air"
    case "iPad5,3", "iPad5,4":                      return "iPad Air 2"
    case "iPad2,5", "iPad2,6", "iPad2,7":           return "iPad Mini"
    case "iPad4,4", "iPad4,5", "iPad4,6":           return "iPad Mini 2"
    case "iPad4,7", "iPad4,8", "iPad4,9":           return "iPad Mini 3"
    case "iPad5,1", "iPad5,2":                      return "iPad Mini 4"
    case "iPad6,3", "iPad6,4", "iPad6,7", "iPad6,8":return "iPad Pro"
    case "AppleTV5,3":                              return "Apple TV"
    case "i386", "x86_64":                          return "Simulator"
    default:                                        return identifier
    }
}
```

then you can use it like this

```
if UIDevice.modelName == "iPhone 4" {
    theNode.xScale = whatever
    theNode.yScale = whatever
}
```

Comment: If this is the right answer, please mark it as so so other people with this issue get the answer